# Google Drive API Search file with 'sharedWithMe' option

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to user Goole Drive API search files parameters from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters. And I have a problem with combining **sharedWithMe** with other available parameters.

I have request.Q = "'directoryId' in parents"; and it worked fine. Now when I've added request.Q = "'directoryId' in parents and sharedWithMe" drive returns empty file collection. But if I use only request.Q = "sharedWIthMe" drive returns all shared-with-me file (but I need data only from directoryId and shared-with-me as a reader). Do you know what can be the problem? Is it some bug or I do smth wrong?

Does " 'me' in readers and 'directoryId' in parents" is equivalent to " 'directoryId' in parents and sharedWithMe"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug. It might be that the query is syntactically correct but there is no such location (like searching for The Statue of Liberty in Russia). Also [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters?hl=en) doesn't provide any example of what you're trying to do. Try performing a follow-up search after the initial 'sharedWithMe' search has returned a response.